# Why python prints integers as float numbers in this program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def hailstone(n):
    print(n,end=' ')
    
    while n!=1:
        if n%2==1:
            n=3*n+1  
            print(n,end=' ')
        else:
            n=n/2
            print(n,end=' ')
            
hailstone(7)
```

---

```
Output: 7 22 11.0 34.0 17.0 52.0 26.0 13.0 40.0 20.0 10.0 5.0 16.0 8.0 4.0 2.0 1.0
```

Hello, I wonder why python prints these integer numbers as float numbers after 22. Thanks.

Comment: You should read-up on coercion rules.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, a/b is a float division so your 22/2 is 11.0

But a//b is integer division so 22//2 is 11.

But also 23//2 is 11, mind you ... but you are only dividing by 2 in even cases anyway, so you shouldn't be concerned with losing fractional parts.